# Owl Carousel show navigation by items instead of always

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

In My project, i have used Owl Carousel and it slides nicely for web as well as responsive mode. 
But There is a issue that if i have only 2 items(or 1 item on responsive mode) then how can i hide navigation ?

My script

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                var carouselElement1 = $('.owl-carousel-Product');
                initialize_owl(carouselElement1);
                function initialize_owl(el) { 
                    el.owlCarousel({
                    dots: false,
                    center: false,
                    loop: true,
                    margin: 15,
                    items: 4,
                    responsiveClass: true,                     
                    responsive: {
                            0: {
                                items: 1,
                                nav: true
                            },
                            481: {
                                items: 2,
                                nav: true
                            },
                            767: {
                                items: 3,
                                nav: true,
                            },
                            1199: {
                                items: 4,
                                nav: true,
                            }
                    },
                    lazyLoad: true,
                    autoplay: false,
                    autoplayTimeout: 3000,
                    autoplayHoverPause: true,
                    autoHeight: false
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Please suggest me how can i fix it. I guess there should be any event for this.
Please help me.
Thank you

Comment: anyone is there to help me please.

Comment: Guys, I solved it     $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({});
var carousel = $('.owl-carousel').data('owlCarousel');

// and then you can use this function on window resize or do whatever you like
if (carousel._items.length <= carousel.settings.items) {
   carousel.settings.nav = false;
}